# Diagram for homotopy

Tags: diagrams, commutative-diagrams

I need to construct with tikZ a diagram like here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category_of_chain_complexes. I tried a lot of time but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm no mathematician, but have you looked into `texdoc tikz-cd`?

Comment: @Christoph90 Yes, but I didn't succed to construct this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.5cm,column sep=1.5cm]
\cdots \arrow[r,"d_A^{n-2}"] & A^{n-1}\arrow[dl,"h^{n-1}" description]
\arrow[r,"d_A^{n-1}"] \arrow[d,"~f^{n-1}",xshift=-1mm] \arrow[d,swap,"g^{n-1}~",xshift=1mm] 
& A^{n} \arrow[dl,"h^{n}" description,swap]
\arrow[r,"d_A^{n}"] \arrow[d,"~f^{n}",xshift=-1mm] \arrow[d,swap,"g^{n}~",xshift=1mm]
& A^{n+1} \arrow[dl,"h^{n+1}" description,swap]
\arrow[r,"d_A^{n+1}"] \arrow[d,"~f^{n+1}",xshift=-1mm] \arrow[d,swap,"g^{n-1}~",xshift=1mm]
& \arrow[dl,"h^{n+2}" description,swap]\cdots\\
\cdots \arrow[r,"d_A^{n-2}"] &  B^{n-1}\arrow[r,"d_B^{n-1}"] & B^{n} 
\arrow[r,"d_B^{n}"] & B^{n+1} 
\arrow[r,"d_B^{n+1}"] & \cdots
\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what function has `description`? i didn't observe difference in result if i omit it.

Comment: @Zarko Hint: look at the `h^{}` letters.

Answer (score 1):

for exercise (i still learn `tikz-cd`) and fun:

- based on [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) answer with (very) small changes
- defined is style for diagonal arrows (`DAS`) for shorter code
- used `'` for swap function: for example `\arrow[d,"g^{n-1}" ',` instead of `\arrow[d,"g^{n-1}",swap,`
- displacement of down arrows is interchanged in comparison to [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) answer
- tried to prettify code in editor

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[
   row sep = 1.5cm,
column sep = 1.5cm,
 DAS/.style = {% Diagonal Arrow with Sloped labels
              dl, swap, sloped, pos=0.3}
                    ]
\cdots \arrow[r,"d_A^{n-2}"]
    & A^{n-1}\arrow["h^{n-1}",DAS]
             \arrow[r,"d_A^{n-1}"]
                \arrow[d,"g^{n-1}" ',xshift=-1mm]
                \arrow[d,"f^{n-1}",xshift=1mm]
        & A^{n} \arrow["h^{n}",DAS]
                \arrow[r,"d_A^{n}"]
                    \arrow[d,"g^{n}" ',xshift=-1mm]
                    \arrow[d,"f^{n}",xshift=1mm]
            & A^{n+1}   \arrow[dl,"h^{n+1}",DAS]
                        \arrow[r,"d_A^{n+1}"]
                            \arrow[d,"g^{n-1}" ',xshift=-1mm]
                            \arrow[d,"f^{n+1}",xshift=1mm]
                & \arrow["h^{n+2}",DAS]\cdots    \\
\cdots \arrow[r,"d_A^{n-2}"]
    &  B^{n-1}  \arrow[r,"d_B^{n-1}"]
        & B^{n} \arrow[r,"d_B^{n}"]
            & B^{n+1} \arrow[r,"d_B^{n+1}"]
                & \cdots
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]